# How to get sum for the values inside specific column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table "selled"  which has three column id, qty, code how to sum all the values in qty column where code = X, I know how to count the number of rows in this column but I want to get the sum of  the values inside these rows.

I am sorry guys i am still beginner and i really appreciate it ,This is the code i am using and it still not working

```
$query="SELECT SUM (qty) as sum_of_qty   from selled WHERE code='$code'";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['sum_of_qty'];
```

Comment: `COUNT` or `SUM` qty values?  Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `SUM` function. Docs:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

```
SELECT SUM(qty) as sum_of_qty FROM selled WHERE code = x
```